# How to create multiple head rows on a table with asciidoctor

Tags: pdf, asciidoctor

I'm using asciidoctor v2.0.17 and try to create a table with multiple rows in a header like

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|Value     |Name                                     |
|          +-----------------------------------------+
|          |Description                              |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| first part of a long table (more than obe page)    |
|      ....                                          |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+

<new page>
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|Value     |Name                                     |
|          +-----------------------------------------+
|          |Description                              |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| next part of a long table (more than obe page)     |
|      ....                                          |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

in a pdf-document. Because this feature was been added to asciidoctor two years ago I've tried it with

```
[%header,hrows=2,cols="1,9",width="100%"]
|====================
.2+h| Value
h| Name

h| Description

| ...
| ...

 ...
|====================
```

But this fails:

- The header contains the first line only after a pagebreak
- the vertical span was been ignored

so the result looks like

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|Value     |Name                                     |
|----------+-----------------------------------------+
|Descriptio|
|n         |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| first part of a long table (more than obe page)    |
|      ....                                          |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+

<new page>
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|Value     |Name                                     |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| next part of a long table (more than obe page)     |
|      ....                                          |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Because the changes done of the issue #1539 are contained in the used version of asciidoctor I assume that I have the right version. Has some one any idea how I can sove the problem?

Best reards,
Ralf Ebert

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this feature was been deactivated by the developers. It is possible to activate this feature by activating the commented-out part in the deleted file:

```
ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-pdf-1.6.2/lib/asciidoctor/pdf/converter.rb
```

(Lines 1921-1925 in version 2.0.17 of asciidoctor)

But it won't work with vertical span.